# Xrandr gives wrong info about screen connections?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, xrandr, displayport

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS I fail to get my second screen to work. Google does not turn up much useful, nothing that has worked yet. So after spent a couple of days searching, I decided to try to both up- and downgrade the kernel, but had no effect on this at all. I then detached the cable for the second screen (USB-C/DisplayPort) and kept only the HDMI between the comp and screen. To my great surprise, when issuing the command `xrandr -q` it wants me to believe I am connected through DisplayPort, which I am not.

I have not seen this talked about anywhere I have looked, but have read several reports of second screens suddenly not working after fresh installs and upgrades, and that xrandr only shows one of two attached screens etc, but no fix or cause. The closest thing would be a mention it may be an issue with the current kernel somehow.

Below is what it looks like. The first command was before I disconnected the other screen - should've shown both, the second after re-installation with that detached - this should have been shown for the HDMI-1 port...

Ideas anyone?

```
$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x47 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 5 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting


$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 621mm x 341mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Are you using x11? 22.04 uses Wayland by default so xrandr won't work correctly.

Comment: Yes, I am using X11. I started using Wayland, and then tested along and ended up with x11 for the moment. I'm happy with either really

Answer (score 0):

**Found the issue** - what is going on is beyond me though, if anyone knows, please enlighten me.
When re-installing Ubuntu I also upgraded the BIOS, and when at that disabled some stuff I don't use, amongst others support for ThunderBolt...

Turns out this is actually needed(?!) for my USB-C ports to function. After enabling it, USB-C now works again. However, Xrandr still thinks my HDMI is DP, but not an issue for me at this point;

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +*DP-3 1920/621x1080/341+3840+0  DP-3
 1: +DP-1 3840/697x2160/392+0+0  DP-1
```